# How to arrange a list in ascending order in prolog?

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

i want to sort my list in ascending order but without using builtin function is that possible?

```
 5  9   3   4   7   10  2   1   5   6
```

if yes then how?

Comment: Yes, you implement a sort predicate.

Comment: as i am new to prolog thats why i asked how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the sorting algorithm yourself, writing predicates. Let’s implement it using [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

The first thing to write is a `min` predicate which relates a list to its minimal element and remaining sublist:

```
% In this clause, the list has a single element.
min([H], H, []).

% In this clause, the head is not the minimal element of the list.
min([H|L], M, [H|R]) :- min(L, M, R), H >= M.

% In this clause, the head is the minimal element of the list.
min([H|L], H, [M|R]) :- min(L, M, R), H < M.
```

Once you have this predicate, it is easy to write a `sorted` predicate which relates a list to the list sorted in ascending order:

```
% In this clause, the list is empty.
sorted([], []).

% In this clause, the sorted list in ascending order is the concatenation of
% its minimal element and the sorted remaining sublist in ascending order.
sorted(L, [M|S]) :- min(L, M, R), sorted(R, S).
```

This sorting algorithm has a time complexity of O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) which is bad, but it is easy to understand and implement. You definitely would prefer to implement a better sorting algorithm, such as [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) which has a time complexity of O(*n* log *n*). The goal here is just to show how this can be done with Prolog.

Comment: selection sort is very far from being the worst, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

We can just express our wishes, and Prolog will take it as its command:

```
ascending(  [], [] ).
ascending(  [A], [A] ).
ascending(   A,  [X,Y|C] ) :-
  select( X, A, B),
  ascending(    B, [Y|C] ),
          X   <     Y.
```

This runs very slowly though:

```
2 ?- ascending( [5,9,3,4,7,10,2,1,5,6], X).
false.

% Execution Aborted
3 ?- ascending( [5,9,3,4,7,10,2,1,6], X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10] ;
false.
```